# Are there sometimes only finitely many square roots of a positive matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:** A positive (semi-) definite matrix has a unique positive (semi-) definite square root. What are its other square roots? In some cases there are infinitely many (such as for $aI$). Are there cases where there are finitely many?

In [this][1] question it is shown that the identity matrix has infinitely many square roots (although of course it has a unique positive square root). But it doesn't seem to address the general question of the square roots of a positive operator. The behavior of the class of matrices

$$\left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt{a} & t \\ 0 & -\sqrt{a} \end{matrix} \right)$$

as square roots of $aI$ seems to be due to the "merging" of the $-\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{a}$ eigenspaces when you square. This might suggest that for a positive matrix with distinct eigenvalues, there are only $2^r$ square roots, with $r$ the rank of the matrix?

**Ideas:** One thing that might narrow it down: if a matrix is normal, will all its square roots be normal, or not necessarily? If we know this, we can go straight to working with eigenvalues.

[1]: [In a finite dimensional vector space a positive operator can have infinitely many square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547694/in-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-a-positive-operator-can-have-infinitely-man)
  [2]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/558072/how-many-square-roots-not-necessarily-positive-does-a-positive-matrix-have

Comment: If the matrix has size $1\times 1$, then it has exactly two square roots.

Comment: Good point! If the eigenvalues are distinct, can we say they are finite?

Answer (score 9):

You are correct. To be precise, we have:

> **Claim:** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix with eigenvalues $a_1\ge \dots\ge a_n$.
>
> (i)  If $a_i=a_j$ for some $i\ne j$, then $A$ has uncountably many
> square roots.
>
> (ii)  If $a_1>\cdots>a_n>0$, then $A$ has $2^n$ square roots.
>
> (iii) If $a_1>\cdots>a_n=0$, then $A$ has $2^{n-1}$ square roots.

**Sketch of proof:** Case (i) has been shown in the body of your question, so let us assume that $a_1>\cdots>a_n$. Since $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable, without loss of generality, we may assume that $A={\rm diag}\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$. Let $Q$ be some square root of $A$. From $AQ=QA$ and $a_1>\cdots>a_n$ we can see that $Q$ must be diagonal. Then cases (ii) and (iii) follow.