# The set of all real square roots of a real matrix cannot be countably infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in End(\mathbb R^n)$ be any endomorphism. Prove that the set of solutions of equation $B^2 = A$ is finite or uncountable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562566/are-there-sometimes-only-finitely-many-square-roots-of-a-positive-matrix).